Need help with a system of 2 very verbose equations
I need to find a $\gamma$ in terms of $a$ and $r$ which solves
$$(a^2+ r^2-2 ar\cos\beta)+(a^2+\gamma^2 r^2-2a\gamma r\cos\beta) - 2\sqrt{(a^2+\gamma^2 r^2-2\gamma ar\cos\beta)(a^2+r^2-2ar\cos\beta)} = k(a^2+\gamma^2 r^2-2\gamma ar\cos\beta)(a^2+r^2-2ar\cos\beta)$$
This equation must be satisfied via $\gamma$ for all $\beta$, so we can take advantage of this to create a system of a couple equations for different $\beta$:
A. If $\beta = \pi/2$
$$2a^2 + (1+\gamma^2)r^2 - 2\sqrt{(a^2+\gamma^2 r^2)(a^2+r^2)} = k(a^2+\gamma^2 r^2)(a^2+r^2)$$
B. If $\beta = 0$
$$2a^2 + (1+\gamma^2)r^2 - 2(1+\gamma)ar - 2\sqrt{(a^2+\gamma^2 r^2 - 2a\gamma r)(a^2+r^2-2ar)} = k(a^2+\gamma^2 r^2 - 2a\gamma r)(a^2+r^2-2ar)$$
$\underline{\text{I'm pretty sure the key to solving this is to first get $k$ in terms of $\gamma$ and then substitute $k$}}$ $\underline{\text{ into either A or B to get $\gamma$ in terms of $a$ and $r$}}$
I first start by using $A$ to create a substitution to put into $B$
$$2a^2 + (1+\gamma^2)r^2 - k(a^2+\gamma^2 r^2)(a^2+r^2) = 2\sqrt{(a^2+\gamma^2 r^2)(a^2+r^2)}$$
And we can make this substitution into $B$ $$\sqrt{(a^2+\gamma^2 r^2)(a^2+r^2)} - a r(\gamma +1) - (a-\gamma r)(a-r) = -kar\Big((\gamma +1)(a^2 + \gamma r^2)-2\gamma ar\Big)$$
Which simplifies to $$\sqrt{(a^2+\gamma r^2)(a^2 + r^2)} = -\Big((a^2 + \gamma r^2)(1+kar(\gamma +1))+2k\gamma a^2 r^2\Big)$$
Squaring both sides $$(a^2+\gamma r^2)(a^2 + r^2) = \Big((a^2 + \gamma r^2)(1+kar(\gamma +1))+2k\gamma a^2 r^2\Big)^2$$
The next step would be to isolate $k$ in terms of $\gamma,a,r$ but I don't think it's ideal to have it be in terms of anything other than just $\gamma$. Does anyone see any errors in my initial substitutions? Or is what I have currently correct, and I should move to isolate k and then onto back substitution?

NOTE: I don't have the answer, but I think my result should be something like $\gamma = \frac{a}{r}$ or $\gamma = \frac{a^2}{r^2}$ or something similar to that.

A small tip. It is more convenient for us to answer your question if your notation is as simple as possible. So took the liberty of letting $r=r_0$ to get rid of the subscripts. I hope you don't mind. Also, pls check if $A$ and $B$ are what you intended.

If you think the solution is "something like" $\gamma=\frac ar$ or something similar what stops you from plugging that in?

@YvesDaoust Yeah I wasn't sure about combining constants when we're trying to isolate $\gamma$, but as Kurt has shown to me, it's actually very simple, I just needed to keep track of the combined constant containing $\gamma$.

Too long for a comment:
Your monster
\begin{align}
&(a^2+ r^2-2 ar\cos\beta)+(a^2+\gamma^2 r^2-2a\gamma r\cos\beta) - 2\sqrt{(a^2+\gamma^2 r^2-2\gamma ar\cos\beta)(a^2+r^2-2ar\cos\beta)}\\ &= k(a^2+\gamma^2 r^2-2\gamma ar\cos\beta)(a^2+r^2-2ar\cos\beta)\end{align}
is of the form
$$
U+V-2\sqrt{UV}=kUV
$$
with obvious defintions of $U$ and $V\,.$ Only one of those two depends on $\gamma\,.$ Let's choose $V\,.$
Writing $W^2=V$ we obtain
$$
W^2(1-kU)\pm 2\sqrt{U}\,W+U=0\,.
$$
Can you solve that for $W$ and proceed?

Yes, I think I can take a stab at it from here. Thank you, Kurt!
